# How to do login and register with php and mysql in fragment?

Tags: android

how to do login and register with PHP and MySQL in fragment?
I need sample code, hope someone can help me

here is my **loginfragment** code:

```
Package com.example.administrator.mosbeau;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 9/1/2015.
 */
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.loginlayout, container, false);
  }
}
```

and here is my **loginlayout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:fillViewport="false">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:maxHeight="54dp"
        android:maxWidth="322dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/lock"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-60dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:background="#ffeeeeee"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
        android:textColor="#ff6d6e71" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:textColor="#ff6d6e71"
        android:background="#ffeeeeee"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:hint="Password" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign in"
        android:id="@+id/btnSignin"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:textColor="#ff6d6e71"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="#fffed4d4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Forgot your Password ?"
        android:id="@+id/textForgot"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSignin"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnSignin"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ff607d8b"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:id="@+id/textSignup"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textForgot"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnSignin"
        android:textColor="#ff607d8b"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login with facebook"
        android:id="@+id/btnLoginfb"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textForgot"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:background="#ff2385ff"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Help"
        android:id="@+id/btnLoginhelp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnLoginfb"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnLoginfb"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#fffed4d4"
        android:textColor="#ff6d6e71"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Skip"
        android:id="@+id/btnLoginskip"
        android:background="#fffed4d4"
        android:textColor="#ff6d6e71"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnLoginhelp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnLoginfb"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I'm new to android so I really don't know how to do that.
I already develop login and register with PHP and MySQL by following tutorials, but it uses activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is good example for the

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Overall steps to do :

1. Create Web-service for login in `PHP`
2. Call that Web-service form android `Fragment`
3. Get response and parse it
4. Show the Result to User

see this link for [working with Fragments](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-working-with-fragments--mobile-5367)

Answer (score 0):

You asked kind of an involved question, especially without being able to see your server side code.

Since you mentioned needing source code, here is the official Android Developers training with source code examples, http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

I'll copy the relevant code in here,

```
public void myClickHandler(View view) {
    ...
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        // fetch data
    } else {
        // display error
    }
    ...
}
public class HttpExampleActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "HttpExample";
    private EditText urlText;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);   
        urlText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myUrl);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
    }

    // When user clicks button, calls AsyncTask.
    // Before attempting to fetch the URL, makes sure that there is a network connection.
    public void myClickHandler(View view) {
        // Gets the URL from the UI's text field.
        String stringUrl = urlText.getText().toString();
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            new DownloadWebpageTask().execute(stringUrl);
        } else {
            textView.setText("No network connection available.");
        }
    }

     // Uses AsyncTask to create a task away from the main UI thread. This task takes a 
     // URL string and uses it to create an HttpUrlConnection. Once the connection
     // has been established, the AsyncTask downloads the contents of the webpage as
     // an InputStream. Finally, the InputStream is converted into a string, which is
     // displayed in the UI by the AsyncTask's onPostExecute method.
     private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
            try {
                return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
            }
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            textView.setText(result);
       }
    }
    ...
}
// Given a URL, establishes an HttpUrlConnection and retrieves
// the web page content as a InputStream, which it returns as
// a string.
private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
    // web page content.
    int len = 500;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
        is = conn.getInputStream();

        // Convert the InputStream into a string
        String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
        return contentAsString;

    // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
    // finished using it.
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        } 
    }
}
...
    InputStream is = null;
    ...
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
...
// Reads an InputStream and converts it to a String.
public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Reader reader = null;
    reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");        
    char[] buffer = new char[len];
    reader.read(buffer);
    return new String(buffer);
}
```

Having done this a few times, though, I'd like to point out some things that will likely bite you when you try to implement this

- Android requires you to do anything that calls a web server in a background thread. http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html
- You are probably going to need some kind of authentication, especially if PHP side you used e.g. Drupal . I would find out if your PHP framework requires e.g. Session auth with a CRLF token or OAuth or a similar scheme. Authentication will involve three steps :

** Sign in

** Retrieve a cookie or token

** Send the token in along with your content in your headers

- Finally you are going to need some sort of data encapsulation layer. I like JSON, some folks like XML. The GSON library, which you can learn more about here, https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html , is the most user and beginner friendly JSON library I know of. In practice I usually use Android's built-in JSONArray and JSONObject though.